# Can I overlap a sprite or a layer on video in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

In Cocos2d-x's sample code `cpp-tests`, there is a `UIVideoPlayer` sample in android platform.

I change the video's position to (0,0) and even add a layer(or a sprite) overlapped on it, the video **just can't be covered any way**(video playing is fine), even the FPS and the vertex count info are the same.

Is it normal? Nothing can overlaps the video? If not, how can I overlap my sprite(or layer) on it?

Answer (score 1):

By default, all non-cocos2d views are on top of everything drawn by cocos2d.

You can only add the video in the background, with cocos2d drawing everything on top.

What you can not do is to have a cocos2d node drawn in the background, draw the video over it, then draw another cocos2d node on top of the video. The reason is simple: cocos2d draws everything to its own view, and there's only one cocos2d view. So you can only change the draw order of everything drawn by cocos2d with some other view, since nodes aren't views themselves.

Comment: I don't understand your answer very well. Do you mean if I create another `GLView` to play video **BEFORE** cocos2d-x's `GLView`, I can archive my goal?

Comment: No, at best you can play the video in the background with *everything* that cocos2d draws on top of the video. This probably requires changing how the cocos2d view is initialized, I suppose there are instructions somewhere like they exist for cocos2d-iphone.

Comment: Really!? That's what I want! But default `GLView` isn't created and setup to that state, how should I change at code to archive that goal?

Comment: Well in cocos2d-iphone you had to set the clear color of the GL view to transparent, and change GL view's framebuffer to 32 bit (RGBA8888). I suppose the same needs to be done in cocos2d-x but I can't say whether it'll work the same way.

Comment: I still can't understand, I only have one `GLView` in cocos2d-x,right? The video now is playing on the top of my all sprites in cocos2d-x's `GLView`, why I change `GLView`'s attributes can work? Even if it is all transparent, my damn video is just OVERLAPPED it anyway, and that isn't what I want.

Comment: Consider the view hierarchy. On iOS the first view is drawn first, then its parents, then the second. If you add the video player view as a subview of the cocos2d GL view, it will always draw on top of it. You need to insert it before the cocos2d GL view. In cocos2d-iphone that means adding it to the cocos2d view's parent (respectively the UIWindow)  and then reordering the views so that cocos2d view comes second.